# Do you capitalise "North" and "South" of England?

Tags: capitalization

When referring to the regions in England, do we refer to them as the "South of England" or the "south of England"?

Same with "South" and "south" - is it capital (or not capital) when using this noun to refer to the regions in the UK?

Regions meaning: London, South West and South East etc.

Also, for the "North-South" divide, is that also capitalised or not?

Thanks.